# Measuring Current, Resistance and power capacity of an Incandescent bulb

Tags: ac, resistive-load

We are making a cheap 1000w load bank, using 10 incandescent bulbs of 100 watts each, connected parallel to vary the load. On a 230V AC 50Hz Home Supply. I am able to measure the current, but when I measure the resistance it dosent match up V=IR. We are building a DC supply and we intend to test the rectified DC on the Load bank. I agree to P=VI and since I am able to measure both V & I, I should get P, but my concern is R dosen't add up and am concerned if I am missing something.

Comment: Hot light bulb filaments don't have the same resistance as cold light bulb filaments.

Comment: the cold resistance is 1/10th the V/I  ratio when hot.  SO it acts more like constant current in the mid-range.

Comment: The temperature coefficient of nichrome wire will be a bit less than that of an incandescent bulb, if that is of any help. Some people use a length of "magnet wire" in a bucket of water - the usual warning about electricity and water applies.

Comment: Summarising various inputs: Incandescent bulbs have an immense hot to cold resistance variation - far more than 10:1 in some cases, Nichrome wire is close to zero change - specs available on web. Also Constantan wire is available. Should be available new but can use wire from eg toaster or heater elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to trust V * I to measure power. As pointed out by Whit3rd, lamp resistance varies with temperature in a non-linear way. You should take care that "V" and "I" measurements are taken within a short time-frame, lest lamp resistance changes between these two measurements.
Heating and cooling of lamp filaments can also create some nasty dynamic effects that your power source may have difficulty dealing with. If your power source is intended to power incandescent lamps, then your load test is realistic.